# Output image from RESTful Service Angular

Tags: angularjs, restful-url

I am new to Angular so to get to grips with it I have been working with a Dummy RESTful service. Right now I have managed to pull the image URL and then push it into an array.

I would like to output this array as an image when the "ng-click" directive is fired.

Any guidance or help would be much appreciated.

```
<p ng-click="outputImageData()">click me</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        {{ image }}
    </li>
</ul>

myApp.factory('getImages', function($http) {
    var imageService = {
      async: function(id) {
          var promise = $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1').then(function(response) {
              return response.data;
          })
          return promise;
      }
    };
    return imageService;
});

myApp.controller("outputImages", function($scope, getImages) {
    var photos = [];
    $scope.outputImageData = function() {
        getImages.async().then(function(data) {
            var photoId = data.url;
            photos.push(photoId);
            console.log(photos);
        })
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using angularjs but generally as a developer, I'm just started so bear with me, please.

I think something like this would work:

```
<p ng-click="updateImageData()">click me</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        <img src="{{photo.url}}">
    </li>
</ul>

myApp.factory('getImages', function($http) {
    var imageService = {
      async: function() {
          var promise = $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/');
          return promise;
      }
    };
    return imageService;
});
myApp.controller("outputImages", function($scope, getImages) {
    $scope.photos = [];
    $scope.updateImageData = function() {
        getImages.async(photoId).then(function(data) {
            $scope.photos = data;
            console.log(photos);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the issue :/

Comment: I'm usually a lazy ass and tend to go 'like this?' and see which part is not working. Could you specify what seems not to be working.